# jQuery: Cross-domain POST on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, cross-domain

I'm trying to make a post request to another domain using the following code

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://domainName.com/api/v1/statistics/1",
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
  });
```

but it gives me the error (404) and it seems that it sees the request as get request no matter what

Comment: [404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) page not found.I think URl is wrong .

Comment: The request is a GET due to the fact that you have told jquery that you are interested in making a JSONP request.  Is that a typo in your dataType option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not POST through JSONP. You can only use GET.

Also the domain name should contain: `http://` to access the external document. I hope you know you have to create a function for using JSONP. The default callback function is called `callback` so your response should be something like:

```
callback({ "data" : "data"});
```

The callback function `?callback=?` will autoomaticly be added to the URL. If you have a rewrite you have to use `$_GET['callback']` to get the callback function.

From the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra
>   "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables
>   caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the
>   URL unless the cache option is set to true.

**EDIT**

Your request will look something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://domainName.com/api/v1/statistics/1",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp : "mycallback",
    success : function(data){
        console.log(data.thiskey); // Will log OK
    }
});
```

Now the request URL to your API will look like this (jQuery will append the `?callback=mycallback`):

```
http://domainName.com/api/v1/statistics/1?callback=mycallback
```

In your response you have to create a function call so it will call the jQuery Ajax function. This result needs to look something like this:

```
mycallback({ thiskey : "OK" }); // The data in this call can be retreived at the success function
```

In the success function you are able to retreive your data like:

```
success : function(data){
    console.log(data.thiskey); // Will log OK
}
```

Comment: can you explain more.. where should i put this callback.. i'm using http:// of course but i have no clue how should i apply your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**CORS**

Further to Niels' answer, you must appreciate that cross-domain data sending is depended on the [CORS policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) of the "target" domain

Basically, "foreign" ajax requests are by default denied by the middleware of the server, unless you use some sort of CORS middleware to create some endpoints to access

If you get your `404` error out of the way, you should look at using something like [Rack-CORS](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) to provide Cross-Domain Origin support for your app (allowing cross-domain asynchronous data transfer)